# How can I set the size of the markers in plotly express sacatter_mapbox?

Tags: python, plotly-express

I am trying to plot some latitudes and longitudes in a map
I do

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(one_line, lat="lat", lon="lon",
                            zoom=15,
                            text = 'point_idx',
                            size='size',
                            size_max=15
                        )
 fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map", margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
 fig.show()
```

where `one_line` is the dataframe with the values (only 17 values)
For some reason this shows the map, I can see the text when I put the mouse there but the marker is not drawn

For an even strange reason in a similar script but with 3176 points I can see the markers
How can I set the marker size so that I can see them

EDIT
The data

```
          lat         lon
0   35.843737  139.870344
1   35.843765  139.870372
2   35.843800  139.870407
3   35.843835  139.870441
4   35.843871  139.870476
5   35.843907  139.870511
6   35.843942  139.870545
7   35.843978  139.870580
8   35.844014  139.870614
9   35.844049  139.870648
10  35.844085  139.870682
11  35.844121  139.870715
12  35.844157  139.870749
13  35.844194  139.870783
14  35.844230  139.870817
15  35.844266  139.870850
16  35.844306  139.870887
```

Comment: Marker size is related to the data to be covered. For example, if the maximum size is 15, then the same marker size will be used if the size column is 15 or larger. Can the target sample data be presented?

Comment: Onlu 17 points and I don't see any of them

Comment: I added a size column and a point index column to your data and ran the code. I get an error, but the marker is now displayed on the map. If I stop specifying the map box style, it appears without error. The country displayed is Saitama, Japan.

Comment: Can I see the code?

Comment: If I stop specifiyng the map box style nothing appears not even the map

Comment: Found the error!. point_idx was a int64. With that it does not plot When I  comment that it plots. There should be a way to convert that column into an object or string....

Comment: Try this: `one_line['point_idx'] = str(int(df.index))`

Comment: @r-beginners with that `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'RangeIndex'`

Comment: Try this: `fig = px.scatter_mapbox(one_line, lat="lat", lon="lon",
                        zoom=18.5,
                        text=[str(x) for x in df.index],
                        size=[x*5 for x in df.index],
                        size_max=15,
                        )`